# htaccess rewrite language with get id

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, lang

Hi i use htaccess for url rewrite and language detection.

I have domain.com/en/page translated to domain.com/page.php?lang=en
it is working great, but if i add a 3rd param to the url, i cant get the lang

ex domain.com/en/page/44  44 is the id

my htaccess rules are:

```
RewriteRule saints/?([0-9-]+) saint.php?id=$1 
RewriteRule photos-and-videos/?([0-9-]+) category.php?id=$1 
RewriteRule various/?([0-9-]+) article.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(en|el)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the 3 rules

```
RewriteRule saints/?([0-9-]+) saint.php?id=$1 
RewriteRule photos-and-videos/?([0-9-]+) category.php?id=$1 
RewriteRule various/?([0-9-]+) article.php?id=$1
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(en|el)/saints/?([0-9-]+)$ saint.php?lang=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(en|el)/photos-and-videos/?([0-9-]+)$ category.php?lang=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(en|el)/various/?([0-9-]+)$ article.php?lang=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

and it is working great

Answer (score 0):

To add an additional perameter, you can use this rule :

```
RewriteRule ^(en|el)/(.+)/?(.*)?$  $2?lang=$1&id=$3 [QSA,L]
```

The 3rd perameter in the rule above is optional, so **/en/page** or **/en/page/foo** both would work.

Reordered/fixed rules

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(en|el)/(.+)/?(.*)?$  $2?lang=$1&id=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule saints/?([0-9-]+) saint.php?id=$1 
RewriteRule photos-and-videos/?([0-9-]+) category.php?id=$1 
RewriteRule various/?([0-9-]+) article.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this does not work. I think it has to do with the first 4 rules.

Comment: It is causing a loop el/saints?lang=el&id=&lang=el&id=&lang=el&id=&lang=el&id=&lang=el&id=&lang=el&id=&lang=el&id=&lang=el&id=&lang=el&id=&lang=el&id=&lang=el&id=&lang=el&id=&lang=el&id=&lang=el&id=&lang=el&id=&lang=el&id=&lang=el&id=&lang=el&id=&lang=el&id=&lang=el&id=

Comment: your first answer helped me a lot. Thanks